# git-parameter plugin in jenkins job builder not working

Tags: jenkins-job-builder

Am trying to configure a jenkins job from jenkins job scheduler and in my yaml i need to configure git-parameter, but when i configure like below it says **"jenkins_jobs.errors.JenkinsJobsException: Unknown entry point or macro 'git-parameters' for component type: 'parameter'"**

parameters:
    - git-parameters:
      name: tag

I tried many combination and names but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Do you have https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-parameter/ installed?

This plug-in is required for `git-paremeter`.  See https://docs.openstack.org/infra/jenkins-job-builder/parameters.html#parameters.git-parameter